# PHP - How to disable auto filling username and password in touch devices (iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, autofill

If the user has saved his username and password in iphone for login, the same are override on another page username and password.

I have tried options like autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false" but didn't worked.

Please suggest !

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @gnasher729 after login, In other pages it overrides username and password (with the saved username and password) even if there is listed some another username and password.